# Mutate returned data in response type class

Tags: angular, typescript

In angular front-end project I have a service function which is connected with back-end API and returns some type response. This type is defined as a user class.

```
someAPICall(param1, param2): Observable<MyClass> {...}
```

`MyClass` response contains `created_at` UTC date. Can I somehow convert `created_at` date in the class? I need something like this:

```
export class MyClass {
 construct() {
    this.created_at = new Date('someOtherDate');
 }
}
```

but it's doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
  someAPICall(param1, param2).subscribe(res => {
    if (res && typeof res.created_at === 'string') {
      res.created_at = new Date(res.created_at);
    } 
    console.info(res); // TODO
  });
```

when MyClass is like:

```
export class MyClass {
    created_at : Date | string;
    // ...
}
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe: https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-ways-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-in-angular-ab912819a78f

Comment: Ok, it makes sense, but I have multiple API calls which use the same response type. That's why I wanted to use something in a single place. Not pipes in views nor modification in every API method. Is that possible at all to move this logic direct into response type class?